# How to copy CRT file on a Nerves device

Tags: elixir, mqtt, nerves-project

I want to copy ca file to establish ssl connection. I am placing the CA inside `lib`

```
lib/
   mymodule.ex #using the ca path here
   mycrt.crt
```

and then using `mix firmware` I am giving the relative path like this

```
 def getPath() do
    {path,0} = System.cmd("pwd",[])
    String.replace(path,"\n","/lib/mycrt.crt")
   end
```

But we run on host using `iex -S mix` so I have to prefix the `/lib` before `mycrt.crt`

I am not sure whether it is properly getting copied in `/lib` or `pwd` is getting the right path after burning on device. Is this a proper way of doing? Because when I am doing `ls` on device I cannot see `mycrt.crt` copied in directory

What is the right way to copy files over device using Nerves?

Comment: I'm not sure. But why don't you use the Path.absname to create the full path, so you wouldn't have problems regarding from which directory you start your application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `lib` use `priv`, so:

```
priv/mycrt.crt
```

Then in code:

```
Path.join(:code.priv_dir(:my_app), "mycrt.crt")
```

See https://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#priv_dir-1.

Alternatively you could use a module attribute to read the file contents at compile time:

```
@crt_bin File.read!("lib/mycrt.crt")
```

Whether you just want the file to be available on the target, or want the module attribute version, I would recommend storing the file in `priv` per: http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#7.4. In particular:

> - `priv` - Optional. Used for application specific files.

and:

> The priv directory holds assets that the application needs during
>   runtime. Executables should reside in priv/bin and dynamically-linked
>   libraries should reside in priv/lib. Other assets are free to reside
>   within the priv directory but it is recommended it does so in a
>   structured manner.